# While loop format in C

Tags: c, unix, while-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [comma separated expression in while loop in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364044/comma-separated-expression-in-while-loop-in-c)

Hi All,
Has anybody ever encountered this format of while loop in C?

If yes, what is the syntax? I am not able to understand this. Please help.

Regards
kingsmasher1

```
  while(printf("> "), fgets(str, 100, stdin), !feof(stdin))
   {

   }
```

Comment: The format of this while loop is the same as the format of every other while loop.  The only "difference" is that the condition contains a comma operator.  Note that using feof in the condition of a while loop is almost always wrong.

Comment: Exact duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364044/comma-separated-expression-in-while-loop-in-c

Comment: So you mean, inside while loop we can give comma and write multiple statements?

Comment: BTW, you miss `)` at the end of the while

Comment: @kingsmasher1 I don't recommend using the comma operator like this in the general case. The resulting code isn't especially readable, and there are pitfalls, like the lack of a sequence point. This example would be much better as a do-while loop. It's conceivable that the comma operator is cleaner in some cases.

Comment: @pmjordan: what lack of a sequence point? Comma operator sequences its LHS before its RHS.

Comment: @Steve Jessop  hmm, looks like you're right, the comma operator *does* act as a sequence point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is equivalent to:

```
do {
    printf("> ");
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
} while(!feof(stdin));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is simple and good one

Answer (score 3):

This is an excellent example of **evil code**. Do not write code like this. It is hard to read and debug. It is useful only in obfuscated C contests or to otherwise demonstrate how clever you are. In some jurisdictions, it may render you liable to charges of compiler abuse. Using code like this may cause subsequent maintainers to hunt you down and LART you with extreme prejudice. In extreme cases, Randall Munroe may make fun of you.

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of the Comma Operator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator Two instances, actually.

The comma operator evaluates the expression on the left hand side of the comma first, then the one on the right, returning the latter as the value of the entire expression.

So in this case, it's equivalent to

```
do
{
  printf("> ");
  fgets(str, 100, stdin);
} while (!feof(stdin));
```

I don't recommend writing obtuse code like this. The comma operator is rarely used - typically in macros which should act like an expression but actually execute a sequence of operations.

Comment: 6.5.17/2 puts a sequence point in `(i++, i++);`. Behavior therefore is defined. That's what "first" means in "evaluates the expression on the left hand side first",

Comment: Yep, you're right, sorry. I've removed the incorrect bits.

Answer (score 0):

That's an abuse of the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

What it does is

```
while(printf("> "), fgets(str, 100, stdin), !feof(stdin))
```

it evaluates each of the expressions separated by the comma operator and discards the values of all but the rightmost one. It uses the value of the right most one as the value of the whole expression. So, you have

```
while (expression) /*...*/;
```

and, your `expression` is

```
printf("> "), fgets(str, 100, stdin), !feof(stdin)
```

That expression:

- prints a greater than sign and a space evaluating to 2; it discards the 2
- reads at most 100 chars from `stdin` into `str` and evalutes to either `str` or NULL if there was an error. That value (`str` or NULL) is discarded
- it sees if the stream `stdin` is in an end-of-file condition and the value is the value of the whole expression (1 if `stdin` is in end-of-file condition; 0 otherwise)

Comment: Is there a valid use for the comma operator, anyway?

Comment: Valid use of comma operator is, maybe, in initialization and/or increment of for loops: `for (j = 100, i = 0; i < 100; i++, j--) /*...*/;`