# while loop gets() twice in C

Tags: c, while-loop, gets

I know that this while loop issue is very common, and it is usually caused by a newline in a input stream. However, I wasn't able to fix my while loop, and I don't really understand why it's happening in my case.

Consider the following example:

```
 int main()
 {
   int option = -1;
   char buffer[100];
   while (option != 10)
    {
     while(printf("Enter menu choice: \n"), gets(buffer), option < 0)
           {
             some code here dealing with buffer and assigning input to option...
           }
     printf("something\n");
     }
    return 0;
  }
```

Ignore the implementation of this code (e.g store the input in integer instead of string, etc.) as it's just a simplified version of my case for while loop. What concerns me is then I have to enter the number twice before it actually goes through the loop.

Output:

Enter menu choice:
1

Enter menu choice:
1

All lights are turned on
Light settings: 1111 1111 1111 1111

I am not sure why it's happening in this case...Thanks!

UPDATE: Thank you for your answers. I have fixed code by rewriting my while() condition

```
while(printf("\nEnter menu choice: \n"), gets(buffer),  option = checkMenuOption(buffer), option < 0 && strcmp(buffer, ""));
```

Comment: You are not modifying `option` anywhere. Add `option++` after `printf("something\n");` if it's until it's a particular value or assign 10 to it at some point.

Comment: Now that's a weird approach for repeating the printing in the condition of the `while()` loop. Extremely unreadable.

Comment: Actually I am taking the integer from char buffer[100] and assigning it to int option.

Comment: Can you post that code? We cannot know for sure if the problem isn't there :)

Comment: Missing semicolon after '`return 0`'

Comment: @user2115641 I've updated my post and hopefully have been able to explain properly why your loop behaved like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The printf() and the gets() are within the `while` test, before the evaluation of `option`.

In fact, with the current behavior you don't actually have to enter the number twice: You have to enter the number once and then type anything so gets() will return.

**Edit:** I added a few details on is how it runs:

- Instruction pointer reaches the very beginning of the `while` statement, begins evaluating its condition

  - calls printf()
  - calls gets()
  - evaluates `option < 0`, which is true.
- Body of the `while` statement

  - code parses string, sets `option` to a value above zero.
- Instruction pointer is looped back to evaluating the condition

  - calls printf()
  - calls gets()
  - evaluates `option < 0`, which is false.
- `while` loop terminates

  - calls `printf("something\n");`

It's visible here that the buffer, once filled by gets(), is only read by the code in the first iteration, and is ignored on the second one.

Comment: Oh, I see. I have fixed my problem by putting the actual code in the condition of the while() after printf() and gets(). However, could you please elaborate on this? Why printf() and gets() run twice here?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I understand what was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

May I recommend that you use [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead of `gets`? It's far safer and can be used to prevent buffer overrun.

Also, I've rewritten your code a little bit, would this do what you're interested in?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int option = -1;

    char buffer[100];

    while (option != 10)
    {
        printf("Enter menu choice: \n");

        fgets(buffer, 100, stdin); /* get input from the standard input
                                      and save it in the buffer array */

        option = atoi(buffer); /* convert input to integer */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If the user typed in '10', the program will quit:

```
$ ./a.out 
Enter menu choice: 
10
$
```

If you want to keep the old code here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int option = -1;
    char buffer[100];
    while (option != 10)
    {
        while(printf("Enter menu choice: \n"), gets(buffer), option = atoi(buffer), option < 0)
        {

        }
        printf("something\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem was that you weren't assigning `option` anything in the loop condition. During the first test, `option` was still not 10, it's only in the body that it becomes 10. After the first run option is assigned 10 (or whatever you've entered) the while loop has still not evaluated it and that's why it prints the statement again and it asks you to enter a value.

You can rewrite the loop like this to test my claim (make sure the code updating `option` is still in the body):

`while(option < 0 && printf("Enter menu choice: \n") && gets(buffer))`

And finally, do not use commas, as statements separated by commas will always be executed (I assume this is not what you want here, in other cases it could be perfectly fine), it's only the last member of the list that is tested for true/false. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364044/comma-separated-expression-in-while-loop-in-c).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I have figured out that if I want to keep my original code I need to evaluate the input in while() condition.

Comment: Yes, and please keep in mind the difference between using a comma separated list and treating every part as a statement to be evaluated as true/false. In the former part, as you've seen yourself, everything but the last statement will be evaluated every time the loop iterates. In the latter you can avoid this as I have shown you.

Comment: I am aware of this fact as that's what I wanted to get, but thanks for your advice!

Comment: Glad to have helped, I myself have very seldom encountered the comma separated list in a loop initialisation, you can easily impress (or confuse) less initiated souls with it :)

Comment: There is nothing "impressive" about it except its obtusity.