# What is the use of "," in while loop condition c++?

Tags: c++, while-loop, comma-operator

```
string command;
string bookName;
while (cin >> command, command != "END")
{...}
```

Here in while loop's condition, there is a comma.
I know that multiple conditions can be added using `&&` or `||`.

But why use `,`?

Is there any certain benefits? Can you please explain the usage and syntax?

Comment: It's the [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364044/comma-separated-expression-in-while-loop-in-c This should be helpful

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561882/what-is-the-advantage-of-commas-in-a-conditional-statement/33562149#33562149

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's the comma operator, also known as the "evaluate and forget" operator. The effect of `a, b` is:

1. Evaluate `a`, including any side effects
2. Discard its value (i.e. do nothing with it)
3. Evaluate `b`
4. Use the result of `b` as the result of the entire expression `a, b`

The author of the loop wanted to express the following:

> Read `command` from `cin`, and then enter the loop body unless `command` is equal to `"END"`

However, they would have been better off using `&&` instead of `,` here, because `cin >> command` can fail (i.e. if the end of input is reached before the word `END` is found). In such case, the condition with `,` will not do what was intended (it will likely loop forever, as `command` will never receive the value `END`), while the condition with `&&` would do the right thing (terminate).

Comment: Excellent catch regarding the infinite loop bug!